# NSWindowController not closing on close

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am creating an instance of `NSWindowController` like the following:

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.mainWindow = [[MainWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];
        [self.mainWindow showWindow:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and then later I'm trying to close the window:

```
-(void)close
{
    [self.mainWindow close];

}
```

But nothing happens. I have made sure that `self.mainWindow` is non-nil, and I have also tried: [self.mainWindow.window close], but to no avail.

Comment: try [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate: self]; instead of [self.mainWindow close];. This method is typically invoked when the user chooses Quit or Exit from the application’s menu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648536/how-to-close-a-window-unload-a-nib